# Python how to plot (x,y) data on a netcdf image

Tags: python, plot, netcdf

I have a large eddy data set like [x,y,diameter], and I have plot a background map of 1440*720 pixels, how can I plot the eddy locations with their diameter in circles on the map? 
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The map I have read is a .nc file which is sea level anomalies, spatial resolution is 1/4°x1/4° on a cartesian grid. So the x(longitude) is 0-1440, and y(latitude) is 0-720. And I have the (x,y) data of eddies, how can I put markers to show the locations of eddies on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib`:

Assuming your data set has the format:

```
data = [[x1,y1,d1], [x2,y2,d2], ...]
```

then

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi 
im = plt.imread(image_name)
implot = plt.imshow(im)

for elem in data:
    # put a blue dot at (elem[0], elem[1]) with diameter elem[2]
    plt.scatter([elem[0]], [elem[1]], s=pi*(elem[2]**2)/4)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! But the map I have read is a netcdf file which is sea level anomalies, spatial resolution is 1/4°x1/4° on a cartesian grid. So the x(longitude) is 0-1440, and y(latitude) is 0-720. Then how can I put markers to show the location of eddies?

Comment: Use [this](http://www.hydro.washington.edu/~jhamman/hydro-logic/blog/2013/10/12/plot-netcdf-data/) to plot the netcdf file and then do the scatter thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to show the image (e.g. `pyplot.imshow`) and plot the data (e.g. `pyplot.plot`), then do this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(map_image)
# the next line prevents subsequent calls to pyplot.plot from changing axes
plt.autoscale(False)
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```